# Hide Elevation Button shadow when I tapping on it

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I hide ElevatedButton shadow, when I tapping on it. Or maybe I can use some differnt button, I need property to change shadow color and elevation. I tried to use ElevationButton(but it doesn't hide shadow when I tapped on it, on the contrary shadow becaming bigger). I alse tried to use RaisedButton, but it doesn't have property for changing shadow color.

Comment: show us your code

Answer (score 2):

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: (){},
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    shadowColor: Colors.transparent,
  ),
  child: Container(),
),
```

You can also use RawMaterialButton

Answer (score 1):

Found solution, you just need to oveeride elevation in ButtonStyle with MaterialStateProperty, and set other parametrs as you need.

```
ElevatedButton(
      style: ButtonStyle(
        backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(activeColor),
        overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(pressedColor),
        shadowColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(shadowColor),
        padding:
            MaterialStateProperty.all<EdgeInsetsGeometry>(EdgeInsets.zero),
        shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<OutlinedBorder>(border),
        elevation: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<double>(
            (Set<MaterialState> states) {
          if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) {
            return 0;
          }
          if (states.contains(MaterialState.focused)) {
            return elevation;
          }
          if (states.contains(MaterialState.hovered)) {
            return elevation;
          }
          return elevation;
        }),
      ),
      onPressed: onPressed,
      child: textBody,
    ),
```